# Python 2.7: Adding new items to Tkinter listbox without adding existing values

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

I am writing a simple bulk file utility. I have two listboxes in the GUI. Listbox1 contains a list of files that exist in whichever directory the user selects. The user can then add selected items in listbox1, to listbox2. Currently this allows duplicate items to be added. I would like to figure out how to check if selected items already exist in listbox2, and only add items that aren't already present.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox
import os, sys



class FileZap():
    def __init__(self, root):

        def getDir():
            dir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir="C:/")
            self.user1.delete(0,END)
            self.user1.insert(0,dir)
            files = (file for file in os.listdir(dir)
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, file)))
            for file in files:
                self.listbox1.insert(0,file)

        def selectAdd():
            selection1 = self.listbox1.curselection()
            for i in selection1:
                selectedFiles = self.listbox1.get(i)
                self.listbox2.insert(0, selectedFiles)

        root.title("Test_App 1.0")
        root.geometry("860x450")    
        self.listbox1 = Listbox(root, width=50, selectmode="multiple")
        self.listbox1.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL, command=self.listbox1.yview)
        self.listbox1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="ns")
        self.listbox2 = Listbox(root, width=50)
        self.listbox2.grid(row=2, column=4)
        self.label1 = Label(root, text="Select a folder: ")
        self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.user1 = Entry(root, width="50")
        self.user1.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.browse = Button(root, text="Browse", command=getDir)
        self.browse.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.button2 = Button(root, text="Add to Selection", command=selectAdd)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, column=3)

        self.quit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.quit.grid(row=8, column=4)


root = Tkinter.Tk()
file_zap = FileZap(root)
root.mainloop()
```

In the above code the function selectAdd() performs the item manipulation. I was hoping to do this by adding another for loop within the function that returns the values in listbox2, and adding items if not in listbox2. However I can only seem to return selected values using .get, I can't figure out how to select all values. Also I'm not sure that this is even the best way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just getting all values currently in the second listbox with `listbox2.get(0,END)` and if there are no duplicates add the selectedFiles:

```
def selectAdd():
    selection1 = self.listbox1.curselection()
    for i in selection1:
        selectedFiles = self.listbox1.get(i)
        list2files = self.listbox2.get(0, END)
        if selectedFiles not in list2files:
            self.listbox2.insert(0, selectedFiles)
```

Comment: Okay I feel stupid now. I was trying to create to new lists and use 'not in' and .append to do this. I didn't realise .get can do this. Thanks very much, works like a charm.